# AngularJS UI-Router "otherwise" state not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My index.html page has 3 views:

```
<header ui-view="header"></header>
<main ui-view="content"></main>
<footer ui-view="footer"></footer>
```

I just changed the site to use these 3 views instead of the initial single view.

All the routes in my app work fine, for example the "home" view:

```
  $stateProvider.state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  data: {
    pageTitle: 'Home',
    access: 'private',
    bodyClass: 'home'
  },

  views: {
    'header': {
      templateUrl: 'modules/header/header.html'
    },
    'content': {
      controller: 'HomeController as home',
      templateUrl: 'modules/home/templates/home.html'
    },
    'footer': {
      templateUrl: 'modules/footer/footer.html'
    }
  }
});
```

My issue is the "otherwise" state in the app does not correctly load the "home" state as it should.  The page is blank, no console errors.  Here's the state in my app.module:

```
angular.module('app').config(function ($stateProvider) {

$stateProvider.state('otherwise', {
  url: '*path',
  template: '',
  data: {
    pageTitle: '',
    access: 'public',
    bodyClass: ''
  },
  controller: function ($state) {
    $state.go('home');
  }
 });
});
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You probably just need to set `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/defaultPath'); `after the state definition

Comment: I haven't seen such a thing before `'*path'`, what do you mean by that?

Comment: someone else created it, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if your wild char works or not.

Ideally I use the following for default routing:

```
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
```